# How to change two or more Div Styles in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to change two or more Div styles with a single javascript line?

```
document.getElementById("searchScroll").style.position="fixed";
document.getElementById("searchScroll").style.margin="-50px";
```

Is it possible to merge the code in ONE line?

Comment: whats wrong with 2 lines - works perfectly well and nice and easy to read - using a single line complicates matters (removing what is already there)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update it using a single line of JavaScript - but i would suggest leaving it as multiple - its easier to read and understand with multiple lines and you dont have to worry about replacing other style values.

You can go up a level and set the `style`, for example :

```
document.getElementById("searchScroll").style.cssText = "position:fixed;margin:-50px;";
```

this will replace the current style .. to add you can use the following :

```
document.getElementById("searchScroll").style.cssText += "position:fixed;margin:-50px;";
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/aDMke/

Comment: This works, but it would also get rid of any other styles already present (like "backgroundColor" or whatever).

Comment: @Pointy added ... no error checking for closing `;` but adds to existing

Comment: @Jivings your right ... updated to use `cssText` but dont like it ! would really prefer to use 2 lines ...

Comment: @ManseUK I noticed that you changed your answer multiple times based on other people’s answers. While it’s probably OK from the OP’s perspective to get a single correct answer that aggregates other posts, it might not be entirely fair to other users that are trying to post a more correct answer than yours...

Comment: @David There is an edit function ... i used it .... just like you did with your answer .... the OP accepted the answer I gave after my edits were complete .... get over it

Comment: @ManseUK In all fairness, I just made a point. If you disagree, that’s all good. No need to get defensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with` (but Crockford won’t like it):

```
with(document.getElementById("searchScroll").style){position='fixed';margin='-50px';}
```

Or add on the cssText property (this is probably what you want):

```
document.getElementById("searchScroll").style.cssText += 'position:fixed;margin;-50px';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V6gCC/

Comment: @Pointy right, not used to handle the awkward `with` syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use cssText property.

```
document.getElementById("searchScroll").style.cssText = "position:fixed;margin:-50px"
```

but i will replace all other inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using jQuery:

```
$('#searchScroll').css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'margin': '-50px'
});
```